# setup of an initial condition using the do_mpc toolbox

Tags: python, estimation, toolbox, software-estimation

I am using the do_mpc toolbox in python. I want to set my own initial condition for the estimator (MHE) but the documentation is not very clear how I can do that. has anyone already done it?
here the link of the toolbox and the specific class
https://www.do-mpc.com/en/latest/api/do_mpc.estimator.MHE.opt_x_num.html#do_mpc.estimator.MHE.opt_x_num

Thank you very much for replying

Answer (score 0):

You have probably found an answer by now, but the `set_initial_guess` function of the estimator suggests that you can assign values to the `opt_x_num` variable directly:

```py
def set_initial_guess(self):
    """..."""
    assert self.flags['setup'] == True, 'mhe was not setup yet. Please call mhe.setup().'

    self.opt_x_num['_x'] = self._x0.cat/self._x_scaling
    self.opt_x_num['_u'] = self._u0.cat/self._u_scaling
    self.opt_x_num['_z'] = self._z0.cat/self._z_scaling
    self.opt_x_num['_p_est'] = self._p_est0.cat/self._p_est_scaling

    self.flags['set_initial_guess'] = True
```

In particular, the above code samples sets each `opt_x_num` component to an instance of `DM` (from `casadi`). The values are computed using the `x0`, `u0`, etc. variables. As the docstrings suggest:

> Uses the current class attributes :py:obj:`x0`, :py:obj:`z0` and :py:obj:`u0`, :py:obj:`p_est0` to create an initial guess for the MHE.

you can set the initial guess contents by setting the `x0`, `u0`, etc. variables. For example, you can call something like:

```py
self._controller.x0 = np.array([100, 200, 0, 0])
self._controller.set_initial_guess()
```

Finally, you can ask for further help by opening a GitHub discussion - https://github.com/do-mpc/do-mpc/discussions